# magickimage montage *.png -colorspace CMYK test.png the result picture changed the color space? i can not understand hwow to fix it?

Tags: imagemagick

i used the command  montage *.png -colorspace CMYK test.png
but finally, the result picture color space has changed.  please help..i just wanna keep the original color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nmow.png)

Comment: Please help!! I just wanna combine the pictures into one picture but not change the colour space......please have a look on my picture ,  the result changed the colour space which makes my result looks like a different colour.........help me !!!

Comment: please me bro!!!  This problem makes me close to crack up!!!  how to fix the colour changed problems!!!!

Comment: I have tried adding the CMYK on the command, but it doesn't work.!!!!.
who is the image processing genius!!! help me!!!! save my life!!!.......brothers!!

Comment: Montage is designed for RGB and does not work well with CMYK colorspace. So do your montage and pipe the results to a new convert command to change the colorspace of the result.

Answer (score 0):

convert CMYK.tif 3.tif -composite result.tif
combine 2 tif files(CMKY colour space[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYr2S.png)) into one picture with the above command.

Comment: convert CMYK.tif 1.tif  -geometry +2000+1000 -composite result.tif
the above command could combine pictures and the location you can define it with -geometry command/